# Как в display:flex перенести последний элемент на другую строку?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть с трока с `col-lg-12`. У нее `d-flex`. Но при адаптиве нужно, чтобы на планшетной версии последний div был на новой строке.
Как его перенести туда? Верстаю с бутстрапом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex">
     <div class="footer_contacts d-flex">
      <div class="footer_contacts_logo">
       <img src="img/logo_footer.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_phone d-flex">
       <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
        <img src="img/phone_icon_footer.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="footer_contacts_phone_number">
        +7(812)509-61-36
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_mail d-flex">
       <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
        <img src="img/mail.icon_footer.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="footer_contacts_mail_email">
        sc_silu@mail.ru
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_site d-flex">
       <div class="footer_contacts_site_icon">
        <img src="img/www_icon_footer.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="footer_contacts_site_isite">
        www.spb-chongqing.com
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-lg-3 footer_contacts_logo">
      <img src="img/logo_footer.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 footer_contacts_phone">
      <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
        <img src="img/phone_icon_footer.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_phone_number">
        +7(812)509-61-36
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 footer_contacts_mail">
      <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
        <img src="img/mail.icon_footer.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_mail_email">
        sc_silu@mail.ru
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3  footer_contacts_site">
      <div class="footer_contacts_site_icon">
        <img src="img/www_icon_footer.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="footer_contacts_site_isite">
        www.spb-chongqing.com
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать этим ответом?

Comment: У нас имеется 4 основных блока, включая логотип. В одной строке 12 колонок, значит для каждого блока выделяем по 3 колонки (прописываем класс "col-lg-3"), это позволит перенести все блоки в одну колонку, при уменьшении разрешения экрана.

Answer (score 2):

Как например:

```css
.footer_contacts {
  background: #27365d;
  color:#fff;
}

.contacts_val {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="footer_contacts">
    <div class="row">      
        
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="footer_contacts_logo">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-9">

          <div class="row pt-4">
            
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="footer_contacts_phone d-flex">
                <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
                  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ccc/fff&text=img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_contacts_phone_number contacts_val">
                  +7(812)509-61-36
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="footer_contacts_mail d-flex">
                <div class="footer_contacts_phone_icon">
                  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ccc/fff&text=img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_contacts_mail_email contacts_val">
                  sc_silu@mail.ru
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="footer_contacts_site d-flex">
                <div class="footer_contacts_site_icon">
                  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ccc/fff&text=img" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="footer_contacts_site_isite contacts_val">
                  www.spb-chongqing.com
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но если Вы хотите именно для своего примера, то помимо `d-flex` нужно задать `flex-wrap` [док.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#wrap) разрешает перенос блоков, если они не вмещаются по ширине. Для планшетов или любого другого разрешения задаются префиксы `.flex-sm-wrap`, `.flex-md-wrap`, `.flex-lg-wrap`.